NDSolveValue - states fewer dependent variables than equations for simple FEM beam model & variables not same shape
This is a simple FEM beam model.  Supported at both ends, uniform load.  Nothing complex.
error message - "There are fewer dependent variables, {u[x]}, than equations, so the 
system is overdetermined"
error message - "Lists {uAB,uBC,uCD} and 
NDSolveValue[{{-u^(4)[x]==0,-u^(4)[x]==0,-u^(4)[x]==0},{
DirichletCondition[u[x]==0,x==0],DirichletCondition[u[x]==0,x==59.4]}\ },{u},{x}\[Element]Line[{{0},{59.4}}],Method->{PDEDiscretization->{
FiniteElement,MeshOptions->{Rule[<<2>>]}}}] are not the same shape.
Here is input -
(*Load the FEM package*)Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*Define variables*)
L = 14.85; (*Distance between supports*)
LAB = LBC = LCD = L; (*Assuming equal distances between supports*)
QAB = 1000; (*Uniform load on span A-B*)
QBC = 1000; (*Uniform load on span B-C*)
QCD = 1000; (*Uniform load on span C-D*)
EI = 1; (*Constant EI for the full length of the beam*)

(*Define the beam geometry*)
region = Line[{{0}, {4*L}}];

(*Define the material properties*)
materialData = {{"YoungModulus" -> EI, "PoissonRatio" -> 0.3}};

(*Define the boundary conditions*)
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 4*L]};

(*Define the load*)
load = {QAB, QBC, QCD};

(*Define the problem*)
pde = Table[
  D[Evaluate[Evaluate[-EI*D[u[x], {x, 2}] + load[[i]]*x]], {x, 2}] == 
   0, {i, 3}]

(*Solve the problem*)
{uAB, uBC, uCD} = 
 NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, {u}, {x} \[Element] region, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}}]

(*Plot the deflection*)
Plot[{uAB[x], uBC[x], uCD[x]}, {x, 0, 4*L}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Span A-B", "Span B-C", "Span C-D"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Distance along beam", "Deflection"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Deflection Plot", PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]

